# Using standardized residuals from a previous chi-square analysis as an IV in a regression

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-regression, chi-squared-test, references

I have an analysis I'm considering, and I'm not familiar enough with the statistical details to tell if there are any potential errors. I've done my best to describe the analysis briefly below.

I conducted a latent profile analysis and have identified six different latent profiles. I would like to examine if there is an impact of 'fit' between participants' social identities and their latent profiles on a dependent variable. For instance, if a participant is one of very few women assigned to Profile 1, are their scores on the dependent variable significantly lower than men in Profile 1 or women in other profiles.

In a first attempt at conducting this analysis, I ran a chi-square analysis (latent profile x gender, for instance) and am using the standardized residuals as an IV in a multiple regression. Is this a valid choice? Is there any literature that addresses analyses similar to this, or recommends a better analytic approach?